# ERROR by trying to build instance via ova GC SDK : generic::failed_precondition: no concurrent builds quota available to create builds

Tags: google-compute-engine, quota

i am trying to build an instnace by using an OVA import from my Cloud Storage.

By executing the command :

```
gcloud compute instances import myinstance --project myProject --byol --source-uri=gs://myBucket/myova.ova
```

I do get the Error :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import)
FAILED_PRECONDITION: generic::failed_precondition: no
concurrent builds quota available to create builds.
```

By checking the Quotas i can't find anything related to that. Which one should be increades and how ? Can someone explain me what does cause this ERROR ? And how i fix it ?

I have checked the Limit "Concurrent Build Limit" in my Quotas. It is set to 10. That's the maximum.

My Account has enabled billing and i get charged every month.

I would appreciate your help an thank you in Advance.
Kind Regards,

A.T

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What more Details do you need ?

Answer (score 5):

I'll preface this by saying I'm a complete GCP noob. I have been struggling with this issue for the last couple of weeks and just managed to fix it.
In my case, I had a CloudBuild trigger set up to listen to pushes to the master branch in my repo, but the build was created under a specific region.
Everytime a build was triggered, I would get the same error.

What I did to fix it was: I created a new build trigger, but left the region as "global".
If your billing account is set up properly, it may also be a case of adjusting the region setting. Good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me as well, I think this is related to Google Cloud Build not working for some regions

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm what HovrCat posted. I tried the same and for some reason when creating a new trigger with the region set to "global" it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).